# How do I publish my MVC site on IIS 7+ with proper URLs?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

When I execute my .NET MVC website from within visual studio, the url points to 
http://localhost:61453/ (I have set this port number).

Now I need to publish this to a different local server, whose IP is 172.21.1.83, so that users can access the website by typing www.mysite.com as the URL.

The site needs to be deployed on IIS 7. How do I achieve this? I tried using the 'Publish' option, but it asks me to enter Server, Site name and destination url. So as far as I understand, I should be entering these:
Server: 172.81.21.83
SItename: www.mysite.com
site url: The director where my deployment artefact will be located.

Is this correct? Also, once I create the deployment artefact, do I just open up IIS manager and follow the prompts to host it?

I tried some online steps regarding this, but I am unable to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Open IIS manager on IIS server -> expand your server -> right click sites -> select Add website. Choose your host name, port, application pool and select directory of source files(Content directory - Physical path). Then you can click publish in visual studio. Choose filesystem as publish method and publish your project to local drive. Then just copy content of published folder on your drive to folder you have selected when creating IIS site(directory of source files mentioned here).

There are other options how to get your site from VS to IIS. You can send files directly via FTP My favourite is web deploy, where you create config file on IIS, load it to your project in VS and just click publish.